# Editing SharePoint "Summary Links" Webpart

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, css, sharepoint

[I can't embed an image but here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbrNO.png)
I need some help modifying a SharePoint page I'm working on while trying to learn the application.  I have no coding background, please explain like I'm 5.  I'm using the Summary Links web part but I can't figure out for the life of me how to complete these things:

1. Change the band color from gray to:  Kobe Bryant (purple), Lebron James (maroon), Michael Jordan (red)
2. Add a logo picture before the following texts "Kobe Bryant" (lakers.png), "Lebron James" (cavs.png), "Michael Jordan" (bulls.png)

Please help! I've been messing with the CSS to no avail.

The band can be modified by editing div.groupheader.item.band but I don't see a way to change it individually for each player. I'm looking for a way to force change these using Java or something.

Comment: Reads like a homework assignment. You want us to do your assignment for you without you putting in any work? I'm sure your course material covers the skills required.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Instead of attcking me (which provides great motivation for me or others to help you, right?), how about you do what the bot suggested in the comment, so we have something to start with.